# Problems installing python-dev

Tags: installation, apt, python, eclipse

I am currently working on a project requiring me to extend Python with a C library, and I will be using SWIG on Ubuntu. Worth noting is that I'm doing this on a computer at my university, and **I don't have access to su or sudo commands.** In order to generate a wrapper file I enter

```
gcc -fpic -c output_test.c interface_wrap.c \ -I/usr/bin/Python2.7
```

This line works perfectly when setting up PyDev on Eclipse, but doesn't work here, which, as far as I can tell from googling the problem, can be solved by installing python-dev. So I downloaded python-dev, v. 2.7.3 for ubuntu and unpacked it. I have been unable to find *any* guide whatsoever that describes a manual installation of python-dev, so I'm pretty much stuck here. After the unpacking, then what? Looking at the unpacked folders, I am able to find that there are two files in the ~/python-dev/usr/bin-folder:

- python-config
- python2-config

Neither is executable. In fact, Ubuntu treats them as broken links. So what am I supposed to do at this point? And why is there such a lack of a comprehensible guides for installing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "unpacking"? Did you try `sudo apt-get install python-dev` ?

Comment: @errokis: He/she isn't allowed to use sudo

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: I supposed "here" referred to his/her computer.

Answer (score 1):

You need some more packages. This should get you all you need (I didn't try to compile anything with it):

```
apt-get download libpython2.7-dev libpython-dev python2.7-dev python-dev
```

(you don't need `sudo` for that).

Now unpack the downloaded `.deb` files into `~/python-dev` (this assumes you don't have any other `.deb` files in your current working directory):

```
for i in *.deb; do dpkg -x "$i" ~/python-dev; done
```

Now everything should be in your `~/python-dev/usr/` tree.

Comment: He should also define to python where to look for the libraries and headers ;)